# Jena, RDF and Jade implementation

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl

I have an OWL ontology and I want to store data as RDF . When I search in the Google I saw Jena library is used for this purpose. But I could not understand how can I represent data as RDF in Jade.. Plz can somebody help me ???

Comment: What does it mean "RDF file"? RDF is a way to represents data, not a file format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jade and Jena are more-or-less independent libraries, so using them both in a project is not hard. Indeed, they have been used in various projects - try a Google search for AgentOWL,for example.

Your agents will need one or more Jena `Model` objects to hold the RDF information they are going to reason with. These models can be loaded into memory in each agent instance, or you can use a persistent store, such as [TDB](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/index.html).

When agents need to send inter-agent messages via Jade, as I recall the default mechanism that Jade uses is Java object serialization (this may have changed, it has been a while since I looked at Jade). Serialization won't work for Jena objects, you'll need to construct a model that contains just the RDF triples you want to send, and then `toString()` that into the content for an ACL message. I'd suggest using Turtle as the serialization format; it's more compact and easier to read.